# Random number generator always picks the same number

Tags: c++, random

I'm making a small "dungeons and dragons" type of program to help demonstrate rand() command to me. It's working just fine, except it always picks 2. Never 1. Help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "welcome to T's version of dungeons and dragons! \n Scenario:";
    int Scenario1 = rand() % 2 + 1;
    if(Scenario1==1){
        cout << "you come across a sleeping traveler, Do you ignore him, or steal his loot?";
    }
    else {
        cout << "you find an old bandit hideout in a cave. Do you ignore, or enter?";
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to seed the random number generator.

Comment: Or use a better generator such as one found in `<random>`. `rand` is actively discouraged.

Comment: does <random> work in C++?

Comment: @Trevader24135, I'm not sure what you're asking. `<random>` only exists in C++.

Comment: It is worth to mention that "[rand() Considered Harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)" (Mr. STL's must watch video)

Comment: Just had to link: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: I changed your title to something meaningful: "programming help using C++" tells us nothing of interest - you're asking a question on StackOverflow, so we know you want programming help, and you have [c++] in your tags, so we know you are using C++.

Answer (score 1):

`rand()` will essentially generate the same series of numbers every time if you don't seed it.

The seed determines how the `rand` function generates numbers.  For better 'randomness', call the following **once at the beginning of the program**, for example as the first statement inside `main`:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

This seeds the random number generator with the value of the current UNIX timestamp, which should be unique enough to guarantee a better illusion of randomness.

More information on `srand` here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/

### Edit

As others have mentioned, it's better to use the functionality found in the `<random>` header, as this is a more modern approach that avoids many of the pitfalls of the `srand`/`rand` paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

`rand()` will always generate the number in same sequence.

To generate totally random number you can use `srand(time(0));` `time()` is available in header file called `#include <ctime>`

Fore more detail please have a look :: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naXUIEAIt4U